# Iterating and setAttribute on a request Scope

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, setattribute

I've got a List of Products obtained from a database query.

In each Product there is a `Date_in` and a `Date_out` variable of **Calendar** type.

What I want to do is pass these Products to a jsp view, so that I can build a table with all their informations. To do so I need to convert the Calendar dates to a more suitable format (like a String), and I've got an utility for this.

My problem is: How can I pass each converted date_in/date_out to the request.setAttribute, for each Product in the List?

Here's what I've got.

in `ProductAction`:

```
List<Product> products = service.viewActiveProducts();
    for(Product product: products) {
        String date_inToString = DateConversionUtility.calendarDateToString(product.getDate_in());
        String date_outToString = DateConversionUtility.calendarDateToString(product.getDate_out());
    }

    request.setAttribute("products", products);
```

in the jsp:

```
<table>
  <tr class="index">
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>Date IN</td>
    <td>Date OUT</td>
  </tr>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.products}" var="product">
  <tr>
    <td>${product.oid}</td>
    <td>${product.date_in}</td>
    <td>${product.date_out}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

(Right now product.date_in and product.date_out are in a Calendar format. I want them in a String format).

Comment: Do you have access to `Product` class? How about adding additional fields for holding string formats of date_in and date_out?

Comment: edit your "Product" class and set date_in and Date_out as String and while fetching from the databse convert it to String and set as String you will get as a String in jsp

Comment: In 'Product' class you can change Date_in and Date_out to string and when you get data from DB, you change that into String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom JSTL function and use it directly in your JSP EL tags.

```
<td>${product.oid}</td>
<td>${nspace:formatDate(product.date_in)}</td>
<td>${nspace:formatDate(product.date_out)}</td>
```

Where `nspace` is the xml namespace assigned to your library and `formatDate` your method. A couple of links:

http://www.noppanit.com/how-to-create-a-custom-function-for-jstl/
http://anshulsood2006.blogspot.com.es/2012/03/creating-custom-functions-in-jsp-using.html

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the best answer since it doesn't alter the Product class. However, I think those links are a bit outdated. This one should be more recent. 
[http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass entire list to jsp by request.setAttribute(String,Object);

```
List<Product> products = service.viewActiveProducts();
request.setAttribute("products", products);
```

Your Product class should be implementing Serializable interface

To get your properties date_in and date_out in string format, convert them into string and have two more properties in Product class with names say dateInString and dateOutString and set their values like

```
for(Product product: products) {
product.setDateInString(DateConversionUtility.calendarDateToString(product.getDate_in()));
product.setDateOutString(DateConversionUtility.calendarDateToString(product.getDate_out()));
}
```

In jsp, you can user JSTL to get the properties or field of Products object iterating list

```
<c:forEach items="${products}" var="product"> 
  <tr>
    <td>${product.oid}</td>
    <td>${product.dateInString}</td>
    <td>${product.dateOutString }</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a `getDate_inString()` and `getDate_outString` methods in Product bean that will print what you want. Then, in the jsp you can use `${product.date_inString}`